# What program can I use on Windows, which is similar to Linux crontab, fcrontab, and jobs can be added with text or json, etc. file?

Tags: json, audio-recording, mp3, text, vlc

I would like to record programmes from an online radio stream. For this purpose I would like to find a program for Windows, which supports timed execution of jobs, similarly like crontab on Linux, and the jobs can be added from simple text file - similarly to crontab - or as a JSON file, etc.

Or equivalently a multimedia program - like VLC, ffmpeg, etc. - which supports recording streams beginning at a given time, and stopping the recording process after a certain time elapsed. Maybe with a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

That program is called `at.exe` on Windows, and it runs as a commandline app, inside the batch/MS-DOS shell. On Windows `at.exe` does the same things as `cron` on Unix,  not as `at` on unix.

The [Wikipedia article about `at`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_(command)) highlights the differences - with screenshots, command options and their syntax, etc. (Scroll down a bit on the article's page.)

The requirements to use `at.exe` with `.bat` files is a bit awkward. But you could put a single command inside that bat file, a call to your custom script (in Powershell, Perl, Python...).

Comment: Curiously, the `at` command is missing from SS64.com: https://ss64.com/nt/

Comment: It's not `at`, it is `at.exe`. Not a built-in shell command. -- If it is no longer installed on newer versions of Windows: As far as I remember, some older programs can be installed from so-called ["Resource Kits"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Kit), big collections of optional files and programs, provided by Microsoft. I don't know how those are called today.

Comment: Right, but SS64 lists external commands as well as internal ones.  Robocopy (robocopy.exe), takeown (takeown.exe), and tracert (tracert.exe) are good examples.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't notice that. Just skimmed the A, B, C entries.